# WordPress サブドメイン管理

Tags: wordpress

WordPress での サブドメイン また サブ ディレクトリ 管理 は どのようにやるのでしょうか ？

Answer (score 0):

公式のサポートページがあります。こちらを参考にしてください。

- [サブドメインをマッピングする](https://wordpress.com/ja/support/domains/map-subdomain/) -- WordPress.com

  > サブドメインを使用するには、マッピングサブスクリプションを追加する必要があります。カスタムドメインが登録されていない場合、またはカスタムドメインが WordPress.com を指定していない場合、登録業者や DNS 設定担当者を通じて、DNS 変更を設定する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます サブ ディレクトリはまたちがうのでしょうか ？

Comment: サブディレクトリ管理が何をどうする作業のことを指しているのか分かりませんでした。何を意図されていますか？　リンクしたページにある「サイトの特定のページにサブドメインをマッピングすることはできますか ?」という FAQ では解決しませんか。

Comment: そもそも提示されてるリンクはSaaSであるところWordPress.comについてであり、WordPress.org(インストール型などといって区別した呼称をすることもあります)とは全く異なるものですが、いずれについての質問なのでしょうか(内容的には.orgのようにみえますが…)

Comment: サブディレクトリはページ毎（1ページ 1ページ）という認識です それをどうやって管理しているのかな という疑問です

Comment: わざわざ WordPress と指定してサブドメイン管理について質問なさっていたので SaaS 版の方の話をなさっているのかなと思って回答したのですが、hinaloe さんのおっしゃるように自前で用意する場合の話をされていますか……？　サブドメイン管理と "サブディレクトリ管理" (?) は全然別の話をなさっているように感じています。